# 'It is a car' What is the subject verb and object here?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjects, direct-objects

I have read english word order is 'Subject Verb Object'

Here Car seems to be the subject, is - verb , then what is it?

If the sentence order is 'Subject Verb Object' , then It should be subject?

Comment: “It” is a “dummy subject.” See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205580/can-it-be-used-with-plural-subject, especially Lawler’s answer, but other good ones as well.

Comment: @Xanne  Lawler doesn't have an answer there, (and this isn't a case of dummy 'it'!)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes he does. This is a dummy it, but there is no "existential" it.
There's an existential there, which comes from There-Insertion.

There are several dummy it's, but this one is the it produced by the Cleft construction.
There is no plural for dummy it. It's it, and that's it.

In general, plural predicate nouns do not require plural subjects.
It's plural verbs that require plural subjects.
Plural verbs are not plural nouns. And vice versa.


edited Apr 13, 2017 at 12:38

CommunityBot
1
answered Oct 31, 2014 at 10:20

John Lawler in exile
16133

Comment: @Xanne My apologies. I stand corrected re a Lawler answer (I was looking for JL's trademark colours which weren't there because he'd had to create a new user account to answer. Instead, the answer has a lurid pink!). However, "it" here is not a dummy subject!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this is a very good question.
Because you are seeing the word car you are assuming that it is the subject but “car” is the object.
The word “It” is the subject and refers directly, in this short sentence, to the car (object).
For example, imagine your friend pointed at a car and said “what is that?”.
You would reply back “It is a car”,
“It” being the subject of what he was pointing at, “is” (verb) and “a car” (object in sentence order) being the description of “It”.
Car is a noun. “It” is a pronoun, and in this sentence represents the noun “car” and is the subject because it appears at the beginning of the sentence and has a simple verb which actualises what “It” is doing. “It”(subject) “is”(verb)  “a car”(object).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But _car_ is **not** the object. _A car_ is the predicate noun.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not qualified, but I think this is simple enough that I can answer.

"It" is the subject. "is" is the copula. "a car" is the predicative expression. As a predicative expression, it expresses a property of the subject. "car" is not a grammatical object here.

"is" is technically a verb, but better understood as a copula.

Also, don't assume the word that follows a verb is always a grammatical object.

I'm getting all this from Wikipedia, by the way:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression

You might want to ask your questions at https://ell.stackexchange.com .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community It's the only (currently) not wrong answer here and is succinct and clear.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the *grammatical* subject with the *topic* or agent in a sentence. The topic is a semantic idea; the topic is part of the meaning.  The subject is a grammatical role; it is part of the syntax.

This sentence has a Subject-Verb-Complement structure. The grammatical subject is the pronoun "It". There is no "object". The verb is "is" and the complement is  "a car".

English sentences require a subject, and English expects complements to follow "be" verbs, so the word it is used to form a syntactically correct  sentence.  In other languages the syntax is different and "car" would be the subject. (In many languages this would be expressed as "Car is" or similar.)

Complements are different from objects.  For example a complement can be an adjective or preposition phrase:

> It is fast.
> It is on the road.

And complements *can't* be made into subjects of passive voice sentences.  You can't say *"A car is been by it".

Comment: It wouldn't do any harm to mention that dummy "it" is a pronoun.

Comment: @BillJ But "it" is not a dummy here! This is a case of referential "it", not "dummy it". Please edit this James!

Comment: Consider "It's a car and thus will  struggle to maintain its value" <-- Control verbs like "struggle" cannot take dummy subjects.

Comment: Whatever.......

Comment: Whether it's referential or a dummy depends on the context. It's a dummy in, for example Q:What is it that he wants? A: It's a car that he wants" or "It is a car that has done the damage".

Comment: As an admirer of your contributions, I'm a bit surprised by your "whatever" response here

Answer (score 0):

Here "It" is the subject, also called the *Introductory It.* The verb *'is'* is a *Verb of Incomplete Predication,* hence it doesn't have any object but the noun *'a car'* as a complement. So, the pattern of the sentence is: *Subject+verb+Complement.*

As a rule, *Be*-verbs (am, is, are, was, were, etc.) do not have *objects.* In the *Subject+Verb+Object* pattern of sentences, the verb should be transitive, i.e. an action verb. Example: *He drove the car*. *It hit a wayside tree.*